# How to hide hr inside the last li using css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to hide the `<hr>` inside the last `<li>`

```
<div class="search-wrappper">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p class="ellipses">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor  sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         </a>
         <hr />
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p class="ellipses">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
         </a>
         <hr />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h3>Headline</h3>
         <p class="ellipses">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolor sit amet  dolor sit amet </p>
         <hr />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h3>Headline</h3>
         <p class="ellipses">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum dolor  dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>
```

---

I can target the last `li` using following css

```
.search-wrapper > ul > li:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

I am not sure how to hide `hr` tag inside this last `li`

Comment: Did you try `.search-wrapper > ul > li:last-child  hr{` ?

Comment: Not directly related to the question but, rather than the extra markup of multiple `<hr>` tags you could do this using `border-bottom` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the child by

```
.search-wrapper > ul > li:last-child hr{
```

you can also use

```
.search-wrapper > ul > li:last-child > hr{
```